# Possible to use Minion font for Math Equations in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I'm doing InDesign production on a science journal and some of the articles use math formatted in LaTeX. Right now the editors generate a PDF from LaTeX and we use those as images for the math formulas (we don't want to reset the math in InDesign.) The math fonts don't match the body text, set in Minion Pro. Editors don't seem able to use MinionPro for their math formulas in LaTeX. The math is all Computer Modern. Is it possible to set LaTeX formulas in Minion? If so, where can I direct them for link on how to do it? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: There's Minion Math http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html It's proprietary and non-free.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply - I will forward this to the editors.

Comment: There are TeX metrics available for MinionPro on CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/minionpro), however, you will have to generate the font files yourself from the OpenType files.  Instructions are in the README.